# How to draw a lines in circle in different angles by using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used below code to draw a line in circle,Now I want to draw 12 lines in different angles with same space & lines should be touched to the circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>

    #straight{
    height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid blue; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(**" for loop value must be displayed"** deg);
    transform: rotate(**" for loop value must be displayed"** deg); 
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:400px;
    } 
    #circle {
      height: 30px;
      width: 31px;
      margin-left: 81px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 2px solid blue;
      border-radius: 65px;
      position:absolute;

    }    
    </style>    
    </head>    
    <body>

                        <div>
                                <div id="circle">                       
                                 <div style="position:relative; top:-40px; left:-385px;">
                                    <div id="straight"></div>

                             </div>
                        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me & thanks in advance

Comment: can you maybe add an image for what you want to achieve, and show what you are currently able to do, or what the problem with your code is?

Comment: If you run this code you can see,I am trying to make a wheel.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68kkow8b/1/).

It uses a function `DrawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)` to draw a line between the given co-ordinates.

Basically, it creates `div`s with thin width and rotate them according the slope.

Looks like a wheel with spokes.

Here is a [wheel in action](http://jsfiddle.net/68kkow8b/2/) if you need.

Here is the snippet.

```js
drawNLines(12, 40, 40, 40);

function drawNLines(N, centreX, centreY, radius) {
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    angle = 360 / N;
    x2 = centreX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * angle * i / 180);
    y2 = centreY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * angle * i / 180);
    DrawLine(centreX, centreY, x2, y2);
  }
}


function DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  if (y1 < y2) {
    var pom = y1;
    y1 = y2;
    y2 = pom;
    pom = x1;
    x1 = x2;
    x2 = pom;
  }

  var a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
  var b = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
  var c;
  var sx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
  var sy = (y1 + y2) / 2;
  var width = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  var x = sx - width / 2;
  var y = sy;

  a = width / 2;

  c = Math.abs(sx - x);

  b = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x1 - x) * Math.abs(x1 - x) + Math.abs(y1 - y) * Math.abs(y1 - y));

  var cosb = (b * b - a * a - c * c) / (2 * a * c);
  var rad = Math.acos(cosb);
  var deg = (rad * 180) / Math.PI

  htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
  div = document.createElementNS(htmlns, "div");
  div.setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid black;width:' + width + 'px;height:0px;-moz-transform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg);position:absolute;top:' + y + 'px;left:' + x + 'px;');

  document.getElementById("circle").appendChild(div);

}
```

```css
#circle {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: It is a good practice to "Accept" and "Upvote" (if allowed) the helpful answer as it helps everyone who visits this question in future.