# How to increase lines in circle by moving slider in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to write a code for increasing the lines inside of a circle by moving the slider,
below is a code which i wrote, it is showing one value but not increasing the other lines while moving the slider.
please help me in this code

````
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #circle {
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            border-radius: 80px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var U = a.value;
        drawNLines(U, 40, 40, 40);

        function drawNLines(N, centreX, centreY, radius) {
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                angle = 360 / N;
                x2 = centreX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * angle * i / 180);
                y2 = centreY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * angle * i / 180);
                DrawLine(centreX, centreY, x2, y2);
            }

    </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

#### Use 'onchange'

Currently your `drawNLines` code runs only once, with a fixed value of N.

My hint to you would be to add an `onchange` property to the `input` tag, which would be a function that re-ran the 3 lines at the start of your script.

```
<input onchange="draw" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

And then put the three lines into a function.

```
function draw(){
  var a = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var U = a.value;
  drawNLines(U, 40, 40, 40);
}
```

If you want to ensure the image is drawn at the outset (without waiting for the user to move the slider) you should make an extra call to draw().

Comment: Not working.. I've placed onchange and should i add any more code?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355981/how-to-draw-a-lines-in-circle-in-different-angles-by-using-for-loop) this is code which i took reference. I want to add a slider to increase the number of lines drawn inside the circle. is it possible???

Comment: The link you added is extremely helpful because there is a piece of code that can be executed by visitors to the site, which helps them understand what you want, and guides them to what you might be doing wrong. Use the "Snippet" tool to add a Snippet of running code to your question, and you are more likely to get precise help.